# FastCGI for DocumentRoot only

Tags: php, web-server, apache-2.4, fastcgi, hhvm

I'm trying to set up HHVM for one of my websites. It is running on Apache 2.4, Ubuntu 14.04. I apologize for not being the most advanced system administrator, I am more in the software engineering end of the spectrum.

I've got HHVM installed when but when I use FastCGI for the entire Apache server, it breaks ownCloud. After a bit of reading, I find that the ownCloud developers are still in the process of getting it compatible with HHVM.

So I want to run just one directory with FastCGI and hence HHVM.

My website which I do want to run FastCGI for is in:
/var/www/website
A sub-directory in here is the document root as per:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/website/www
```

(Some of the code lives above the document root for the website; classes, etc.)

ownCloud is in:
/var/www/owncloud
And has the configuration:

```
Alias /owncloud "/var/www/owncloud/"
<Directory "/var/www/owncloud">
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

I've tried quite a few things in apache2.conf without success.

```
ProxyPass / fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www
ProxyPass /owncloud/ //127.0.0.1:80/owncloud
```

­

```
ProxyPass /var/www/website/ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/website
```

­

```
ProxyPass /website/ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/website
```

­

```
<Directory /var/www/website/>
    SetHandler fastcgi-script
    SetHandler proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000
</Directory>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like you wish to proxy things to your fast cgi process unless the URI starts `/ownlcoud/`. You just need to tell mod_proxy **not** to proxy the requests to `/owncloud/`. So you need to add

```
ProxyPass /owncloud/ !
```

*before* your proxy directive to your FCGI process. You can add other exclusions in the same way if you need to.